# Postfix conditionally forward email

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, mail-forwarding

How do you set up automatic email forwarding based on conditions like:

forward if from emailaccount@domain.tld

forward if from domain is **domain.tld**

forward if subject contains word 'Urgent'

and so.

I'm only able to forward (redirect) all emails from one mailbox to certain email address.

Comment: This kind of use-case is better left to a [mail filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_filtering) instead of the SMTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need procmail and a procmail recipe similar to this:

```
MAILDIR=$HOME/.maildir/
DEFAULT=$MAILDIR
LOGFILE=$MAILDIR/from
VERBOSE=yes
SHELL=/bin/bash

:0 wf:
* ^From: emailaccount@domain.tld
! myemailaddress@gmail.com
```

Note that you will probably have to play around with the From regex. That will match some, but by no means all From headers for that email address.

The other conditions you mentioned:

```
*^From: .*domain.tld

*^Subject: .*domain.tld
```

I highly recommend you make use of the procmail log file (location mentioned above) and check that mail is being parsed and processed as you expect.